# Creating a Button to Add Images in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, button, imageview, addition

I am making a game and I need to have a button that when pressed will add an image (ImageView) to the screen, and when pressed again will add another image in a different position. This button has to be able to be pressed and add images until the game ends. My issue, however, is that I am relatively new to programing and I don't know how to make such a botton, or if such a button is even possible. If you need more info just tell me and I will provide all that I can. Thanks if advance for any help I can get!

Comment: Jamman00, Stack Overflow is not the best place for a question like this. This site is geared towards people who have a specific code related issue. You are asking a "where should I begin" question. I would recommend reading the official Apple documentation on UIButton and UIImageView or browse through some tutorials online (e.g. raywenderlich.com). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Jamman00.. Check out my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @suraj! I'm new to stack overflow so it won't let me vote for your answer but when I get the reputation I need I'll be sure to do that!

Comment: @Jamman00.. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to create **`UIImageView`** Programatically, paste the code on button press event. It will create new UIImageView with the size and co-ordinate you provide

```
  UIImageView *imageX =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,120,120)];
  imageX.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
 [self.view addSubview:imageX];
```

change **`x,y,width,height`** of **`UIImageView`** as per your need.

**Swift:**

Declare `UIImageView` with image name,

```
 let imageName = "sample.png"
 let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
 let imageX = UIImageView(image: image!)
```

Now set position to `UIImageView`

```
 imageX.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 120, height: 120)
 view.addSubview(imageX)
```